# Verilog syntax explanation

Tags: syntax, verilog

I'm viewing a verilog code and I've met a strange syntax "<+" which I could not find any kind of explanation to it, i hope there are some users that can tell me what does it to

so here is the line

```
V(out) <+ transition(aout, td, tt);
```

if you need more information of the verilog code.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not part of Verilog but Verilog-AMS, it might also be part of Verilog-A.

The spec is available from [Accellera](http://www.accellera.org/downloads/standards/v-ams).

Example usage from section 1.3.4.1 of Verilog-AMS 2.4 2014:

```
module shiftPlus5(in, out);
  input in;
  output out;
  voltage in, out; 
  analog begin
    V(out) <+ 5.0 + V(in);
  end
endmodule
```

My understanding is that the `<+` is used to describe voltage and current flows between nodes in your AMS models.